# How to put variable inside string-resources?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to put variables inside string-resources? And if yes - how do i use them.

What i need is the following:

`<string name="next_x_results">Next %X results</string>`

and put an int in place of the %X.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

```
<string name="meatShootingMessage">You shot %1$d pounds of meat!</string>  


int numPoundsMeat = 123;
String strMeatFormat = getResources().getString(R.string.meatShootingMessage, numPoundsMeat);
```

Example taken from [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-format-strings/)

Comment: FYI, Resources.getString(int resId, Object... formatArgs) is another method similar to String.format(), which takes the resource id and the Object arguments.  Lets you skip that last step.

Comment: The flags' documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 36):

Just pass it throught getString() function as formatArgs Object.

```
int nextResultsSize = getNextResultsSize();
String strNextResultsSize = 
     getResources().getString(R.string.next_x_results, nextResultsSize);
```

XML:

```
<string name="next_x_results">Next %1$d results</string>
```

Answer (score 17):

```
<string name="message">You shot %1$d pounds of meat! Put Second Variable String here %2$s and third variable integer here %3$d</string>
int intVariable1 = 123;
String stringVariable2 = "your String";
int intVariable3 = 456;
String strMeatFormat = getResources().getString(R.string.message, intVariable1, stringVariable2 , intVaribale3);
```

Comment: How did you assign a string value to int in `stringVariable2`?

Comment: @salman By using %2$s , I have assigned string value to string on 2nd place, not int

Answer (score -3):

yes,you can use.
after adding tag to string.xml file and then to retrrive the the same in your .java file you can follow this.

AndriodApp

String str = getResources().getString(R.string.name);