# error in string.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to put variable inside string-resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854647/how-to-put-variable-inside-string-resources)

string.xml file give error in the following lines.

Error :Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" 
     attribute?
    - error: Found tag  where  is expected

```
 <!-- Search failure message. -->
<string name="no_results">No results found for \"%s\"</string>
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12605846/645270) might help. About using the `%` symbol

Answer (score 1):

If you need to format your strings using `String.format(String, Object...)`, then you have to put your format arguments in the string resource in the correct way.
Replace your string with the following:

```
<string name="no_results">No results found for %1$s</string>
```

-

```
Resources res = getResources();
String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.no_results), "your text");
```

Comment: I replace the code but it is not working

Comment: what's the logcat output?

Comment: logcat show error message

PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed