# How do you use an integer from the resource file within a string in the same resource file?

Tags: android, string, integer

Is it possible to use an integer:

```
<integer name="minstringlength">7</integer>
```

within the same resource file but within a string:

```
<string name="nametooshort">Please enter a name longer than @integer/minstringlength characters</string>
```

Comment: Why is that necessary?

Comment: No this is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you want to use different minimum limits based on device configuration. You can't use the `@integer/minstringlength` in the string content, so I think the best you can do is have a format argument and build the string yourself like this:

```
<integer name="minstringlength">7</integer>
<string name="nametooshort">Please enter a name longer than %1$d characters</string>

int nameMinLength = getResources.getInt(R.integer.minstringlength, 0);
String nametooshort = getString(R.string.nametooshort, nameMinLength);
```

This assumes you are using an Activity/Fragment, otherwise you need a `Context` in order to use `getResources()` and `getString()`.

Answer (score 0):

It can not be done in resource file.

As xml contains static content and also from [android string-resource doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) there is no sub tag or nested tag of `<string>`

It task can done easily in java file

```
getResources().getString(R.string.minstringlength);
getResources().getInteger(R.integer.nametooshort);
```

OR
[Follow this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854647/how-to-put-variable-inside-string-resources)

```
<string name="meatShootingMessage">You shot %1$d pounds of meat!</string>

int numPoundsMeat = 123;
String strMeatFormat = getResources().getString(R.string.meatShootingMessage);
String strMeatMsg = String.format(strMeatFormat, numPoundsMeat);
```