# Have a changing variable in string resource file in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

So I am trying to set a string in the string xml resource file but in the middle of the string I need to use a variable defined in my java class, id rather not just split the string into two, is there a way that I can make a variable in the string that I can change in the java class

Comment: I recomend you to pass for this thread [Put variable inside String resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854647/how-to-put-variable-inside-string-resources)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass all the parameters that you want to a string resource.

Example:

```
<string name="string_resource"> My name is %1$s and I am %2$s years old </string>
```

To pass the parameters use the following function:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.string_resource, "MyName", "myage");
```

In kotlin is very similar:

```
getString(R.string.string_resource, "MyName", "myage")
```

Comment: i just tried to put this into my java function in another file but the getResources() turned red, and said "Cannot resolve method 'getResources' in 'questionCreator'"

Comment: Ah i see i just had to set the context, Thank you :)

Comment: I don't recomend you to pass context as parameter between classes. Pass the string as parameter from activity or fragment